# What is the difference between fuzzy neural networks and adaptive neuro fuzzy inference systems?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, comparison, fuzzy-logic

I have, like you see, just a general question about the combination of fuzziness and neural networks. I understood it as follows

1. Fuzzy neural networks as a hybrid system: the neural network helps me to find the optimal parameters related to the fuzzy system, for example, the rules or the membership function
2. Adaptive neural fuzzy inference systems (ANFIS): the NN helps me to find the optimal parameters related to the fuzzy inference system. What are some examples here?

I cannot intuitively grasp the difference between these two.

Comment: I don't see any difference between these two. The question leads to what you actually mean by a "fuzzy neural network" and an ANFIS; don't you mean the same, that is, layer 1 are the inputs, layer 2 the application of the antecedents membership functions, layer 3 the rules, layer 4 the consequents (apply inverse membership function to rule strength) and layer 5 the final combined output?